# Changing the default WordPress search action

Tags: search

I recently completed a WordPress site design, and I'm just struggling with one bug: when a user clicks the "Search" button without any content in the text field, they are redirected to a list of posts. Is there a way to modify this action? Ideally, if the text field is empty, the user will be redirected to the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default WordPress action is to [redirect to the homepage](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11330) when the search is blank - just what you want! Do you have any plugins or .htaccess settings that may be changing this?

Comment: You're right, thanks very much. I inherited this site from another developer who built the homepage using a template page and didn't include a default index.php file; I've fixed the problem. Thanks!