# If searched in a category show different 404 page

Tags: pages, search, 404-error, categories

Is this possible? I have a `searchform` that searches for certain categories. If there is no post, it will show me a `404 page`... Can I change this page to something else? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty search returns home page, how to return not found search page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/empty-search-returns-home-page-how-to-return-not-found-search-page)

Comment: Seems like the actual problem is not the template but the empty search. Just marked it for others to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the code of your `404.php` to conditionally show other stuff with `is_search() { ... }` or you can use the `search.php` [Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

Comment: What difference will `is_search` make? It does not get my category? How do I do that?

Comment: It's a [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and it allows you to check if you got a search results page.

Comment: Ah, so the is_search goes in the place where I want a different output? Well then, I guess I have to try that. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this in `404.php`, but it did nothing `<?php if (is_search() {
echo 'blabla'; 
});?>` What is wrong with this one?

Comment: Have you read the other Q/A I linked in the comment to your answer?

Comment: Yeah answer 3 and 4 come close, but will that solve it? I mean, I have is_search, alright, but how do I say: if I am searching for categories than do something?

Comment: First you need to get the search working. Care about categories (other conditionals available for that) later on.

Comment: I have tried setting `is_search` on the 404 page, but that did nothing. What do I have to do now than? I honestly don't know it.

Comment: Reading the answers on the linked question on how to _fix an empty search_. Sorry, but I can't read it for you :)

Comment: You don't get it... The search thing is fine, I can make a different search.php, that's not the problem.. I now just want to get that page only if I am searching categories. That's not answered in that topic.