# How to modify search.php to not show pages only show posts

Tags: loop, search

I want to modify search.php so that it only shows posts and not pages.  Can you help?

Here is the loop in search.php:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: I realized the Avada theme offers this as an option. Not sure if this counts as an answer. However, I may not actively followup on responses to this question for now.

Answer (score 1):

The search template is way too late to change anything: The pages are searched already here, and your page numbers would be wrong. Do not alter the output, alter the query.

Filter `posts_search` instead, and if there is a search term, filter `posts_where_paged` and remove the post type you don’t want to be searched.

Sample code:

```
is_admin() || add_filter( 'posts_search', function( $search )
{
    empty ( $search ) || add_filter( 'posts_where_paged', function( $where ) {
        return preg_replace(
            '~post_type IN \((.*)\'page\',?~',
            'post_type IN (\1',
            $where
        );
    });

    return $search;
});
```

Comment: I am very new to Wordpress.  Is this code to be placed in functions.php.  Wondering if you want to explain the code, alternatively I can just try to use it

Comment: Your code will not work if the user will search blank string .any solution for that ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes, there is [a separate solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/empty-search-returns-home-page-how-to-return-not-found-search-page).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and I was already on that page and it seems non of the 3 solutions are working at least for me :(

Comment: @toscho another problem I am facing with your solution is all newly created pages are comming in search result !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on this a while back: [Excluding Certain Posts Or Pages From Search Results In WordPress](http://darrinb.com/notes/2009/excluding-certain-posts-or-pages-from-search-results-in-wordpress/)

But the long and short of it is:

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    };
    return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

You can add that to your theme's `functions.php` file.

What it does is filter the main database query WP runs *before* it actually runs, and tells WP to only look for posts.

Answer (score 0):

replace your loop with this and let me know if this work.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <?php if (is_page()) continue; ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This didn't work.  I tried to create another page with my search term and it shows up.