# make link to search page

Tags: search, links

I have a search Icon in menu section of my site and looking for a way to when a user click on this search icon, redirected to the search page. in the search page, there is a search form and also search result is shown in this page.
Is it possible to make a link to search page without changing search url?

unfortunately in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/link-to-search-page-without-search-parameter) link I didn't find the right answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just like cybmeta in [the answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/link-to-search-page-without-search-parameter) you are linking to said:
see [Creating a search page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) in the codex. Read it carefully. Create a Template like described, add a new page in the backend and choose as template your new search-template, that is now in the template-dropdown. Now you can set a link to this new page and reach it without performing a search.